# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/util/context/ContextView

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, project-reactor, azure-sdk-for-java

I am upgrading the azure sdk for java to version 12.21.1. The spring boot version is 2.1.6.
I am using the following dependency in gradle : implementation 'com.azure:azure-storage-blob:12.21.1' .

I am using the following code to create BlobServiceClient :

```
String accountUrl = "https://" + accountName + ".blob.core.windows.net";
 StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);

try{
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().credential(sharedKeyCredential).endpoint(accountUrl).buildClient();
}
```

But it is throwing an error at runtime :

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/util/context/ContextView] with root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reactor.util.context.ContextView
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
BuiltinClassLoader.java:581
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
ClassLoaders.java:178
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
ClassLoader.java:522
    at com.azure.core.http.policy.HttpPolicyProviders.addAfterRetryPolicies(HttpPolicyProviders.java:52) ~[azure-core-1.37.0.jar:1.37.0]
HttpPolicyProviders.java:52
    at com.azure.storage.blob.implementation.util.BuilderHelper.buildPipeline(BuilderHelper.java:128) ~[azure-storage-blob-12.21.1.jar:12.21.1]
BuilderHelper.java:128
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:135) ~[azure-storage-blob-12.21.1.jar:12.21.1]
BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:135
    at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder.buildClient(BlobServiceClientBuilder.java:114) ~[azure-storage-blob-12.21.1.jar:12.21.1]
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Are you trying to create BlobServiceClient using java sdk? Is that your requirement?

Comment: Yes. I want to upload / download files from blob using java azure sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was some dependency conflict between spring boot version and swagger . I upgraded spring boot to 2.7.10 and swagger to openAPI. This issue was resolved after that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/util/context/ContextView

This could be because of missing dependency in your application. Check if you have added the required dependencies to your project's classpath.

I have reproduced your requirement to upload/download file using Azure Java SDK.

Below are the dependencies which I have used in my application.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-storage-blob', version: '12.16.0'
implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-storage-spring-boot-starter', version: '2.2.5'
implementation group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.4'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Note the Access token of your storage account in the Azure portal:
[image]

I have created the simple API to call this method which is creating the file and downloading the file from Azure Blob Storage.

```java
@PostMapping("/upload")
public  void  uploadFile(@RequestParam(value  =  "file")  MultipartFile  file)  throws  IOException  {

// Code To Create and File In Blob Storage
String  str = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storage_account_name>;AccountKey=storage_account_access_key;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
OffsetDateTime  expiryTime  =  OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(1);
BlobSasPermission  permission  =  new  BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true);
BlobServiceSasSignatureValues  values  =  new  BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(expiryTime,  permission).setStartTime(OffsetDateTime.now());
BlobContainerClient  container  =  new  BlobContainerClientBuilder().connectionString(str).containerName("<conatiner_name>").buildClient();
BlobClient  blob  =  container.getBlobClient(file.getOriginalFilename());
blob.upload(file.getInputStream(),  file.getSize(),  true);
String  sasToken  =  blob.generateSas(values);
// Code To Create and File In Blob Storage

// Code To download the File From Blob Storage
URL  url  =  new  URL(blob.getBlobUrl()  +  "?"  +  sasToken);
HttpURLConnection  httpConn  =  (HttpURLConnection)  url.openConnection();
int  responseCode  =  httpConn.getResponseCode();
// Check if the response code is HTTP_OK (200)
if  (responseCode  ==  HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)  {
// Open input stream from the HTTP connection
InputStream  inputStream  =  httpConn.getInputStream();
// Open output stream to save the file
FileOutputStream  outputStream  =  new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\win10\\Downloads\\data.txt");
// Read bytes from input stream and write to output stream
int  bytesRead;
byte[]  buffer  =  new  byte[4096];
while  ((bytesRead  =  inputStream.read(buffer))  !=  -1)  {
outputStream.write(buffer,  0,  bytesRead);
}
// Close streams
outputStream.close();
inputStream.close();
System.out.println("File downloaded");
}  else  {
System.out.println("Failed to download file: "  +  httpConn.getResponseMessage());
}
httpConn.disconnect();
// Code To download the File From Blob Storage
}
```

Calling the API which I have created and it is generating the url to download the file which has been uploaded as shown below:

[image]

Uploaded the file to Azure Blob Storage using the above code:
[image]

By using the above code, downloaded the file as *data.txt*.

[image]

Comment: Are you using spring boot version 2.1.6 in this case? I know this should work with new versions. But I want to resolve this issue with spring boot 2.1.6.

Comment: Yes, it will work with spring boot 2.1.6 version. I have checked and verified. Attaching [Image](https://i.imgur.com/ky5AbSC.png) for your reference.